# Unable to import Libraries even though Installed in Anaconda on Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, anaconda, importerror

I am using Ubuntu 18.10(dual Boot win10), I have installed anaconda (conda version- 4.6.7) on ubuntu. After this Installation I installed Pycharm via snap on Command Prompt. Since Pycharm(version - 2018.3.5) didnt Detect my python Location automatically I set the python Interpreter via

Adding Location ->System Interpreter (As I didn't want any Venv) -> Path

[image: Location of Python in Anaconda and OpenCV being enlisted in Library List in Pycharm]

But when I try to import opencv in Pycharm it says

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

[image: Python3.6 in Anaconda Bin]

Python3.6 in Anaconda Bin is shown to which I have linked in Pycharm (I have also tried other Python files there as well but no luck)

When I run in Terminal: `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`

It shows:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6
/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/local
/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg', '/usr/lib`/python3
/dist-packages']
```

So could anyone help me out in this?? Thank You in Advance!!

Edit 1:

I am also unable to access any of the libraries from terminal Itself. So Could anyone help me with that as well. Should I export path of this Python in Anaconda bin folder to bashrc file in Ubuntu?

Edit 2:

The libraries affected is not just opencv. There are few other Libraries like Portaudio which are affected as well along with Opencv

Comment: The problem with opencv is probably https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21345

Comment: As for the built-in terminal - try 2019.1 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/, it should autoactivate conda env in the terminal by default.

Comment: Its not just with opencv, There are few other libraries like PortAudio also being affected.